# how to check if the user input is floating number or not

Tags: java

I have to get a user input which will be a float. Then i need to check whether it is a valid float or not. As for example if the user inputs some character it will display an exception. So i need to properly handle it.

```
amount = scanner.nextFloat();

while (amount != (float) amount)
{
    System.out.println("is not a valid amount");
    System.out.print("Enter the purchase amount for Customer " + (count + 1) + ": ");
    amount = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Please help me

Comment: `scanner.nextFloat();` will throw exception if the value is non-float.... what is really your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856140/receiving-float-from-scanner-input-java i suggest you to check this one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `hasNextFloat()` like this:

```
     while(scanner.hasNextFloat()){...
```